# How to make a standalone program in ChucK audio programming language?

Tags: chuck

How do I make a standalone executable application (desktop, on server or mobile apps) in Chuck?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but two things ...

1. If you need ChucK to run on another system, just load it.
2. I you are looking to share your composition, there is a function to write the output to an external file in some audio format such as .wav. That file can be replayed on any other system of you choice. Of course, it'll also play from a web site.

Basically there is no "standalone" ChucK system other than the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a runnable app/patch like you can with MaxMSP at the moment. The simplest solution is to just download the [MiniAudicle IDE](http://audicle.cs.princeton.edu/mini/). It comes bundled with a version of ChucK so you can skip over all the command-line stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an app for PureData for example, you will need to use libPd to use PureData objects inside your app.

For Chuck you can try to use [libChuck](https://github.com/briansorahan/libchuck), or use Chuck sources in your C++ app.